# Practical way for separate Entity classses (DTO) from EDMX

Tags: c#, entity-framework, edmx, three-tier

I have a 3-tiered application

DAL has EDMX file that EF6 generated it automatically from database (DB First mode).
I have BLL and UL layers too.

But, when I want to use BLL methods in UI, I must add DAL assembly to UI layer (because of return types of methods)

```
List<Person>
```

Person define in EDMX (DAL)] **(this my problem)**

**How** I can separate classes (DTO) from EDMX file and create as separate assembly?

**How** can I prevent adding DAL Assembly (whole EDMX) to the UI layer?

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I would do. To decouple the DAL from the UI, you will need a "middle tier". Consider the following diagram.

[image]

The middle tier is widely know as the *service layer* or the application layer.

Everytime the `Person` data passes from one layer to another, it is "mapped" to its equivalent class for that specific layer.

The following snippets makes up the very basic example of a service layer. I did not include the other details such as AutoMappers and other general practices.

**The `PersonDto`**, defined in the middle tier, represents the `Person` entity.

```
public class PersonDto
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**The `PersonService`** class. It encapsulates the data access and business logic, and returns only the `PersonDto` (instead of the entities). It is how the UI communicates with the domain.

```
public class PersonService
{
    public PersonDto GetPersonById(int id)
    {
         Person person = dbContext.Persons.Find(id);
         
         // Mapping in action.
         var personDto = new PersonDto()
         {
             FirstName = person.FirstName,
             LastName = person.LastName,
         };

         return personDto;
    }
}
```

This `PersonService` is what the UI code sees, it does not know about the data access or the business logic. It only knows about the services.

The services should encapsulate your business logic, decoupling the UI from the BLL and DAL.

Comment: A better analog of `Person` in UI Layer is `PersonViewModel`, since `PersonModel` is `PersonDTO` in UI Layer based on MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Good question, the accepted wisdom is that you define a different Person for each tier/layer (DAL, BLL and UI) and then write code to map between each layer.  There's [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) which can make life easier.

Now consider a real-life application with 100 to 1,000 entities.  This pattern does not scale well.

I suggest using the [Code First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/data/jj193542.aspx) approach to EF.  And passing the same object between all your layers.

Comment: Do you have any sample that implement these layers with automapper that you suggested ?

Comment: No I don't, because this pattern is not scalable and I never use it.  I'm sure if you google automapper you can find examples.

Comment: I would say the opposite. A real life appliation with 100 to 1000 entities benefits the most of using different representations of the same object as that makes the different layers independent of each other. I would however not create a monolite application with 1000 entities but divide it into several smaller applications.

Answer (score 1):

Just move the TT files for the POCOs to a different project and leave the EDMX TT files in the DAL. That way you have essentially DTOs/POCO in their own model project, and that can be referenced wherever it is needed.